# Order By using Firebase

Tags: typescript, firebase, ionic-framework, google-cloud-firestore

I'm working on an Ionic project and when I want to display firebase documents on screen, I want to order them by date, which is a field of type date in every document of my collection:

Here is the code that I'm using to bring firebase documents into my application.

```
constructor(private aF: AngularFirestore, private aS: AuthServiceService) {
    this.aF.collection('orders', ref => ref.where('location', '==', 'Store Name Example')).valueChanges().subscribe( data => {
      this.userOrders = data;
    });

  }
```

Any help would be awesome!

Comment: Wat is the question

Comment: Please read the documentation and make an attempt from what you learn there: https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/order-limit-data#order_and_limit_data

Comment: Already tried that! But it just won't show 0 results on screen!

Comment: There's nothing in your code that would perform any kind of ordering so the question is unclear. Take another look at the documentation link and direct your attention to the use of `.order(by...`. It's also helpful to provide and example of your Firebase structure so we know what the collection and documents look like.

Answer (score 0):

See Firestore documentation for information how to order and limit data: https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/order-limit-data

```
constructor(private aF: AngularFirestore, private aS: AuthServiceService) {
    this.aF.collection('orders', ref => ref.where('location', '==', 'Store Name Example').orderBy('date'))
        .valueChanges()
        .subscribe( data => {
            this.userOrders = data;
        }
    );
}
```

To be able to order date you have to store fields in Timestamp type in Firestore: https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.firestore.Timestamp

If you store date in an unorderable string, then you cannot order it. You can order date stored e.g. in `yyyymmdd` format or in a double.

To solve it, you can fetch your data and resave it with Timestamp data type.

Comment: Already tried that! But it just won't show 0 results on screen!

Comment: @RogelioSalazar So before you filter results, you have some results on screen, but after orderBy(...) is applied, then no results are shown and no errors are in console? Are you sure, you store date in date format and not in string?

Comment: Thanks for the quick response again! I just checked and on firebase it's showed as a String and not timestamp. Any solution for that? And no, I'm not getting any errors on console.

Comment: Thankyou very much! Got it done now!

Comment: @RogelioSalazar *If you store date in a string, then you cannot order it.* is not accurate. A date can have this format `yyyymmdd` and in that case it's easily orderable - but it's got to be in that specific format. Additionally, some use cases store the date as a double, which again is orderable. If the reference is to a [Firestore Server Timestamp](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/add-data#server_timestamp), then that is orderable as well.